# Open UITableview or view when the main UITableView cell selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which has master records in it's cell. When the user  selects a cell, some detail **record is displayed on the same table** and this record would be set below that particular cell.
One more thing is the cells that are below the selected cell of the master table will be displayed below the detail view.

In short I want to design a popup that will display the details of selected cell below that particular cell and rest of the cells(cells below the selected cell)  of master will be moved down, so that the detail popup can be accomodated between the selected cell and the cells below it.

Comment: you really need to concentrate on your English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Take int selectedCellIndex in your .h file, initialize selectedIndex with -1
//Take BOOL isSelected in your .h file

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  selectedCellIndex = indexPath.row;
  isSelected = YES; 
  [yourTable reloadData];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
      if(indexPath.row==selectedCellIndex)
      {
           return 100;
      }
      return 50; //Your default cell size
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tV cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //after creating your cell

    if(isSelected && selectedIndex>-1)
    {
        //Show your custom View , something like [cell.contentView addSubView:customView];
        isSelected = NO; //Reset
        selectedIndex = -1;  //Reset
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this 
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method . In here, You can allocate a new `UIView` every time the user clicks on the cell and display your information in it.
If you have any queries please feel free to reply . :)

Check these projects out, maybe they will of some help ...

[Combo Box](https://github.com/floriankrueger/iOS-Examples--UITableView-Combo-Box)

Comment: i have to try that but problem is that Master cell not going to down

Comment: i cant understand with wat u mean by master cell ..... ??? See my edited answer for help...

Comment: ok i will try to explain u Master cell is the main data of table   suppose 1 joke, 2 idia, 3 expanation... ok now when user press joke cell then the detail of joke will display just below it, and idia and expanation will dispay after that now u got my Qsn?

Comment: Ohk ... so wat you really have to do is expand your cell ... then you dont need to add another view.... use this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html